# What's wrong with this pseudo code for leap year?

Tags: python, pseudocode

What should be the correct pseudo code using if else end if

```
input Year 
if(Year % 4 == 0 and Year % 100 != 0) then 
    display "It is a leap year" 
else if(Year % 400 == 0) then 
    display "It is a leap year" 
else 
    display "It is not a leap year" 
end-if
```

Comment: If you simply input year, then it is a string, you should convert it to integer.

Comment: No. I am not talking about syntax or type. Just assume year is holding some integer value . Tell me the flaw in control flow

Comment: if you wrote the actual code, what's your error when you run/compile? post your code so others can help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your logic is listed in reverse order. The pseudocode for this should be:

1) If the year is divisible evenly by 400, it **is** a leap year.
2) If the year is not divisible by 400, but is divisible by 100, it is **not** a leap year.
3) If the year is not divisible by 400, and also not divisible by 100, but is divisible by 4, it **is** a leap year.
4) Else it's **not** a leap year.